# how can I be more efficient

Tags: matlab, for-loop, indexing, while-loop

How can I be more efficient in the following Matlab code? use a while loop? I would have to continue adding more if syntax for my purpose. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
TimeLagM = 6;2;3;1;2;10;25;60;2;5;10;80;24;1;2;3;

p=0;
count=zeros(length(TimeLagM),1));

for i=4:length(TimeLagM)
    if TimeLagM(i,1)>30
    count(i,1)=count(i,1)+0;
    elseif TimeLagM(i,1)==30
    count(i,1)=count(i,1)+1;
    elseif TimeLagM(i,1)<30
        p=TimeLagM(i,1)+TimeLagM(i-1,1);
        if p>30
        count(i,1)=count(i,1)+1;
        elseif p==30
        count(i,1)=count(i,1)+2;
        elseif p<30
            p=p+TimeLagM(i-2,1);
            if p>30
            count(i,1)=count(i,1)+2;
            elseif p==30
            count(i,1)=count(i,1)+3;
            elseif p<30
                p=p+TimeLagM(i-3,1);
                if p>30
                count(i,1)=count(i,1)+3;
                elseif p==30
                count(i,1)=count(i,1)+4;
                elseif p<30
                count(i,1)=count(i,1)+5;

                end 
            end
         end
    end
end
```

Comment: elseif p<30
            p=p+TimeLagM(i-2,1);

p is changing as summed with TimeLagM(i-2,1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives the same results as your code:

```
TimeLagM = [6;2;3;1;2;10;25;60;2;5;10;80;24;1;2;3];

thresh = 30;
maxBack = 3;

p=0;
count=zeros(length(TimeLagM),1);

for i=maxBack+1:length(TimeLagM)
   p = TimeLagM(i);
   s = 0;
   while (s < maxBack && p < thresh)
      s = s + 1;
      p = p + TimeLagM(i-s);
   end

   if p > thresh
      count(i) = count(i) + s + 0;  % i don't know what these values mean
   elseif p == thresh               % so i couldn't give them meaningful names
      count(i) = count(i) + s + 1;
   else % p < thresh
      count(i) = count(i) + s + 2;
   end
end
```

The `while` loops calculates the sums in `p` and remembers how many elements it had to go back in `s`. This way you only have to calculate `count` in one place. This assumes that `count` might be initialized to something other than zeros in the future; otherwise, you could shorten the assignments to `count(i) = s + 0` (or 1, or 2).

The result for the given data is:

```
count' =

   0   0   0   5   5   5   1   0   1   2   3   0   1   2   3   4
```

---

For the case when we don't have a fixed value for `maxBack`, we want to keep incrementing `s` as long as `i-(s+1)` is a valid index, or greater than zero (the `+1` is because we immediately increment it in the loop). That means we would want `(i-s) > 1` and we can start the `for` loop from `1` rather than `maxBack+1`.

```
for i=1:length(TimeLagM)
   ...
   while ((i-s) > 1 && p < thresh)
   ...
```

If you want to keep the option of doing both, have a fixed `maxBack` or not, you can include all three conditions in your `while` loop:

```
   while ((i-s) > 1 && s < maxBack && p < thresh)
```

Then, if you don't want to specify `maxBack`, just set `maxBack = intmax`. (Actually, any value `length(TimeLagM) - 1` or greater will work.)

Comment: This is excellent! Thanks "beaker... any suggestion when     maxBack is unknown

Comment: You want the number of elements to go back to be limited only by the range of the input matrix?

Comment: in case we only know that sum is max 30 (i.e. thresh=30) but do not know the maxBack =3

Comment: Be sure to accept the answer if it solves your problem.